# code line lcd.scrollDisplayLeft (); no working

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, lcd, arduino-c++

I use the library "LiquidCrystal_I2C.h" and "Wire.h".
The code line lcd.scrollDisplayLeft (); does not run the function.

Do I need to put this before / after the Lcd.print?
Should I put in after delay?
Is it related to the library?
It's just part of the code

```
  lcd.clear;
  lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
  lcd.print("press Up to set turn on");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("press down to set turn off");
  Setting = true;
```

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean with "no working"? does it not compile? does it not have the desired effect? how do you use that function? please provide more code. the function scrolls the display contents to the left.

Comment: Does not run the function,  lcd.clear;
        lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
        lcd.print("press Up to set turn on");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("press down to set turn off");
        Setting = true;

Comment: please provide your code. "does not run the function" is pretty meaningless

Comment: lcd.clear;
        lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
        lcd.print("press Up to set turn on");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("press down to set turn off");
        Setting = true;

Comment: That's part of the code

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalScrollDisplayLeft

> **Description** Scrolls the contents of the display (text and cursor) one
>   space to the left.

So you clear the LCD, then you scroll an empty LCD 1 space to the left and then you print something. I don't know what happens after as you did not show your entire code.

I don't know how the LCD behaves. Either the scroll is ignored if there is no content or you do not recognize the 1 space change.

In most examples I've seen, this function is used in a loop. Your question suggests, that you did not consult the reference manual.